# Need help understanding inconsistent behaviour and KMS error when deploying changes via CDK

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cdk, amazon-kms

We are using CDK to create s3 buckets in different regions and to manage a codepipeline which deploys to these cross region and cross account buckets.

We have seen some inconsistent behavior lately when we deployed changes to the pipeline (Add a permission to Codebuild role).

We were getting the following error:

```
Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals. (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocumentException;
```

- We do not explicitly create KMS keys. The KMS keys and its policy were auto generated during CDK deploy.
- To resolve this error, we destroyed the existing S3 buckets and the pipeline and re-deployed it with a different name. The 1st time the deploy was successful in deploying the S3 buckets in all regions except for ap-southeast-2 (With the same error). The second time we rinsed and repeated, it deployed fine.
- We are not sure what is causing this behavior. We wanted to confirm if this is a known bug or something we need to change in our code to resolve this inconsistency.

Following is the KMS policy auto-generated for ap-southeast-2 using cdk synth when it was failing to deploy :

```
"KeyPolicy": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": [
               <Truncated>
              ],
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "AWS": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "arn:",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
                      },
                      ":iam::<Bucket_ACCOUNT_ID>:root"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              },
              "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
              "Action": [
                <Truncated>
              ],
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "AWS": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "arn:",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
                      },
                      ":iam::<Bucket_ACCOUNT_ID>:root"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              },
              "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
              "Action": [
                <Truncated>
              ],
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "AWS": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "arn:",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
                      },
                      ":iam::<Pipeline_Account_ID>:role/<role_name>"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              },
              "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
              "Action": [
                <Truncated>
              ],
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "AWS": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "arn:",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
                      },
                      ":iam::<Pipeline_Account_ID>:role/<role_name>"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              },
```

Comment: Please post the package.json/equivalent version control of the chosen language so we can see what version you're using.

Comment: @lloyd We are using Python 3.7.5

Comment: We are facing the same issue again when we are trying to update the stacks.

Comment: You guys figured any solution yet? Same issue here.